# Problema jar externo criar arquivo no tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

Boa tarde.
Estou com um problema que o Crawler4j (um jar externo) tenta criar arquivos e pastas em uma aplicação no tomcat mas apresenta o seguinte erro:

Couldn't create this folder: /data/crawl/root

Como posso fazer para permitir que o tomcat crie arquivos e pastas?

O código fonte encontra-se em https://github.com/MarcelorjOliveira/CrawlerSpring

Desde já grato,
Marcelo

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia pessoal.

Depois de um bom tempo tentando finalmente consegui responder o problema.
No comando eu pedia para criar a pasta /data/crawl/root pos eu achava que ele ia criar esta pasta a partir do contextpath do tomcat, mas o que está escrito aí é que vai criar a partir do diretório raiz e no linux normalmente usuarios comuns não tem permissão para escrever no diretório raiz.
Descobri isso a partir de testar a mesma aplicação no windows :-( e percebi que ele escrevia a partir da raiz do windows.

É isso aí pessoal.
Obrigado.